# WindowsPhone CreateBindingSet testing

Tags: mvvmcross

I am now moving from my code behind xaml dp binding to using CreateBindingSet, as I believe it will be easier to maintain on long run. Previously to confirm that I haven't missed any binding, I had a Windows Phone Test project with a generic test routine - that would parse a view for all the controls, and confirm that each has a correct binding. I did this using

```
    element.GetBindingExpression(dependencyProperty) // from System.Windows
```

and that's worked beautifully - validating all my views.

But now as I am changing over, all these tests are failing. Has anyone any suggestions on how I can test same thing with when the binding is applied using CreateBindingSet and .Apply.

Thanks in advance.

Rana

**Reasoning behind the Madness**

Being a lazy sod, I dream of a day where my View would be shared across all platforms; until then, the following would do (I have most in place and working)

BoilerPlate class that would be shared between all platforms:

```
#if __IOS
    ... needed namespaces
#else ....

public partial class FirstView
{
    private new FirstViewModel ViewModel
    {
    get { return (FirstViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    }

    private void CommonBinding()
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();

        // do common bindings
        set.Bind(PageText).For(c => c.Text).To(vm => vm.PageText).OneTime();

        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

Then View in Touch would be:

```
public partial class FirstView : MvxViewController
{
    public override void LoadView()
    {
        // create
    }

    public override ViewDidLoad()
    {
        CommonBinding();
    }
}
```

In theory, Views in other platform would be almost similar; just different inheritance (MvxActivity with OnCreate, and OnViewModelSet)/(MvxPhonePage with xaml/alternative, and Loaded Event for binding).

Finally, a common testing way to ensure that all the items has binding set somehow. In my mind, until autoview is supported in wp8, it's just the way to have as much shared code as possible.

I have just started on droid, and trying to make the layout compatible with xibFree, which I have already used in my touch project. If this works, I can then have shared layout between droid and touch (perhaps I should be looking at autoView anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not sure what value these tests add that much value to your application - these feel like they are operating at a level of "duplicating code" rather than actually testing any functionality.

However, this is very much down to personal opinion, and if you do want this level of testing, then I think you could do this by:

1. Inherit a class from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.BindingEx.WindowsPhone/WindowsBinding/MvxWindowsBindingCreator.cs
2. Override `ApplyBinding` so that you can capture at test time the calls made for each element
3. Register this class with ioc as the `IMvxBindingCreator` in your test harness
4. Use the captured lists of binding requests in your tests

Comment: Thanks Stuart; sorry about the late reply; iOS been kicking my ass. I will try out your suggestion and see what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: added some thoughts on why

Comment: Stuart, one quick question about my idea; I need to have a namespace for all my views like Core.Linked.Views; I haven't tested it, but I am sure everything all fall down for not finding the views (different namespace); any thought?